# Sending batch query parameters for GET request in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fetch-api, web-frontend

I have been trying to send over a batch query for a certain function that I wrote in typescript and uses fetch api. Herein is the code for the same:

```
    getBatchBlobsList(componentId: number): Promise<any> {
        let activeUrl = new URL(this.serverAddress);
        let targetUrl = new URL(activeUrl.origin + environment.apiBasePath + '/get_batch_blob_list');

        let params: { [name: string]: string } = {};

        if (this.customLookupAddress != '') {
            params['lookup'] = this.customLookupAddress;
        }
        if (this.customGatewayAddress != '') {
            params['gateway'] = this.customGatewayAddress;
        }
        if (params) {
            Object.keys(params).forEach(key => targetUrl.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));
        }

        let request = { component_ids: [componentId] };

        return fetch(targetUrl.toString(), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'GET',
            body: JSON.stringify(request),
        });
    }
```

But it says that I cannot send over batch query parameters in the request body when it comes to get request. Specifically, this is the error that I receive.
[image]
I was wondering what the correct way would be to solve this issue? Thank you in advance for your assistance :)

Comment: Well, it says that `GET` requests cannot have a body, then you shouldn't pass a body. Your question is about query params but the problem isn't there

Comment: I see. But in this case, how do I send a list of numbers as a parameter since I cannot use the request body?

Comment: If you're not the owner of the server, you should talk with the owner. Usually these items are joined with a comma and then parsed by the back-end, but if they're many then you could consider transforming your request method to POST